# NoMethodError: undefined method `datastore' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used the dragonfly gem for uploading images to my app, i've also tried linking it to S3.However when i deployed it to heroku, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `datastore' for main:Object
/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

here is the dragonfly.rb file

```
require 'dragonfly'

if Rails.env.production?
    datastore :s3,
              bucket_name: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
              access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
              secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],
              region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
              url_scheme: 'https'
else
    datastore :file,
        root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
        server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
end

# Configure
Dragonfly.app.configure do
  plugin :imagemagick

  secret "baaa65a6761943c5b52bfb927ffbe193bcb03858bf1bd73fa3d655f8208a1c39"

  url_format "/media/:job/:name"

  #datastore :file,
    #root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
    #server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
end

# Logger
Dragonfly.logger = Rails.logger

# Mount as middleware
Rails.application.middleware.use Dragonfly::Middleware

# Add model functionality
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  extend Dragonfly::Model
  extend Dragonfly::Model::Validations
end
```

I've also added the ENV's directly to heroku

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not actually used Dragonfly before, but looking at your code, I think the error you're getting is because you're calling datastore out of the scope of Dragonfly, unless Dragonfly has a global mixin that adds the `datastore` method to the application.

Essentially, a little re-org should resolve this for you.
Could you try:

```
require 'dragonfly'

# Configure
Dragonfly.app.configure do
  if Rails.env.production?
      datastore :s3,
              bucket_name: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
              access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
              secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],
              region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
              url_scheme: 'https'
  else
      datastore :file,
        root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
        server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
  end
  plugin :imagemagick

  secret "baaa65a6761943c5b52bfb927ffbe193bcb03858bf1bd73fa3d655f8208a1c39"

  url_format "/media/:job/:name"

  #datastore :file,
    #root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
    #server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
end

# Logger
Dragonfly.logger = Rails.logger

# Mount as middleware
Rails.application.middleware.use Dragonfly::Middleware

# Add model functionality
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  extend Dragonfly::Model
  extend Dragonfly::Model::Validations
end
```

Basically, that brings your datastore accessor within the scope of Dragonfly.
Let me know if that works.

Comment: You sir, are a legend. That was it! THANK YOU